# How do i make boxes(div's) place fill a remaining space

Tags: css, html

Im currently making a site where i have modular boxes in certain sizes (100%, 75%, 50%, 25%, 33% and 66%). The reason for doing that is that i want an easy way to add stuff to my layout.

It works flawlessly if the boxes are of the same height and if the leftmost box is higher than  the right boxes (a 50% box with  double height on the left, and two 50% boxes with standard height on the right).

I'm using float:left and have put margins on the boxes.

so my question is, how can i make the second box automatically place itself under the correct box?

picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C58kd.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have to write properly nested structure for that..
try this

```
<div>  -- left portion (float left)
    <div></div> 
<div></div>
</div>

<div>  -- right portion 
</div>
```